# How does the speed of light sameness in all 4 cordinal directions prove that the speed of light is constant?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

From my reading of Einstein's experiments on the speed of light it is my understanding measured the speed of light in the 4 cardinal directions - North, East, South, and West - and found the speed the same in all directions and from this somehow concluded  that this meant the speed of light was constant.

It seems to me that if a photon is emitted in any direction its vector and speed would be added on to the local reference direction and speed. So why wouldn't it be equal?

Comment: what do you mean by "the local reference direction and speed"?

Comment: all measurements for light, show that it obeys special relativity,  that is why the speed of light is postulated constant. It is part of special relativity postulates

Comment: Have you actually looked any of this up, or is this your "intuition" speaking?

Answer (score 3):

There are some interesting misconceptions in your question.

Einstein was a theoretical physicist- he did not make measurements of the speed of light. He was famous for his 'thought experiments' in which he reasoned through logic what would happen if experiments were conducted.

You mention the four cardinal directions, but you have overlooked two, namely up and down- space is three dimensional, remember.

There were 3 reasons why Einstein considered that the speed of light was a universal constant.

Firstly, experiments by other physicists (most famously Michelson and Morley) suggested that the speed of light was always the same regardless of the speed and direction in which their experimental apparatus was moving relative to space- this did this by taking measurements in two directions at different times of the year when the Earth's orbit around the Sun meant we would be travelling in different directions.

Secondly, Maxwell's equations for EM radiation suggest that light has a constant speed regardless of any frame of reference.

Thirdly, Einstein took the view that the speed of light ought to be independent of reference frame, because all of physics should be.

Since Einstein published his ideas, they have been confirmed by countless experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Einstein did no such experiments himself. His assertion that the speed of light would be exactly the same for all inertial frames was not based on any experimentation at all. It was instead one of his fundamental postulates.

The velocity of light does not add to the velocity of its source because this would give rise to effects preceding their causes. Here is why:

Imagine a fire engine coming towards you at tremendous speed on a straight road. Imagine that the velocity of the light from the engine was added to the speed of the engine.

Now imagine a small car on a cross street, approaching the main road on a path which would cause the engine to collide with it at the intersection. The engine swerves to miss the car.

Since the velocity of the light coming at you from the engine is greater than the velocity of light coming at you from the small car (which is NOT moving towards you), you would receive the light from the engine first- and therefore see it swerve BEFORE the small car has entered the intersection.

So in a world without special relativity- where the velocity of the source is added to that of the light leaving the source- you would see effects preceding their causes.

Comment: I don't think this thought experiment works too well. You would see the fire engine swerve before you see the car entering - but this is only a statement about what you see (that is, signals from past events). Such a world would be messy to navigate all right, but that there is a causality problem here is not obvious to me.

Comment: It is also not obvious that the fire engine would be able to see the car soon enough to swerve in the first place, because the light coming from the car would be reaching it just at is it about to collide. On the other end the car would maybe have had plenty of time to stop, BTW my point here is not to say this answer is bad, but that it is definitely not intuitive.